# Insert an list in Django 1.9.2 database sqlite3

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I want to store a list in database of Django .which model field i should use and how. I tried ArrayField but it does not take list.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models
class signup(models.Model):
    userid=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    list=ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True),size=5,null=True)
    score=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: ArrayField is specific to PostgreSQL. What does you list look like? Is it all integers? Are you going to need doing queries on the list?

Comment: the list consists of integers. I need to read and modify each element in list

Comment: You can try storing them in a `CharField` by converting the list to a string while storing (`";".join(my_list)`) and back to a string while reading (`my_model.list.split(";")`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a default type for the `ArrayField()`, in this case, it needs to be defined as `default=list`.

Also, **you can't use keywords such as `str`,`list`,`int`, etc. as names of variables!**

Your code should look something like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models
class signup(models.Model):
    userid=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    lst=ArrayField(
        models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True),
        size=5,
        default=list,
        null=True
    )
    score=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```